# Reading border color value form parent's background-color, and transparent parent's background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent-child

I have a div, How can get its border color from its parent's background-color, and transparent the background-color on the parent. All in a jQuery or JS code.

e.x. The code is something like this:

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>



    <style>

    .parent {
    background-color: #333;
    }
    .child {
    border-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

Now, I want the child border color turns into #333 (the parent's color), and the parent's background color (#333) becomes transparent.

**I want to do it based on parent-child relationship not the names of the divs.**

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change child's *border-color* with parent's *background-color*

```
var child = $('.child');

child.css({
  'border-color': child.parent().css('background-color')
});
```

Change parent's background-color to transparent

```
child.parent().css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

Do you need this for multiple elements?

Comment: Thank you so much! No I just wanted for a single element and it worked just fine.